# query.include() not fetching subclasses when used inside ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have subclassed ParseQueryAdapter to fetch "Post" items (subclass of ParseObject) and populate a listview. The Post class has a field "postauthor" which contains a pointer to the creater of the post (ParseUser). In the `ParseQuery<Post> create()` method, I have created the query as

```
@Override
public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Post");
    query.include("postAuthor");
    return query;
}
```

Now, I expect each "Post" object in the `getItemView()` method to contain the ParseUser in its "postAuthor" field without fuurther network access as [documented](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-relational-queries) by Parse.com.

```
@Override
public View getItemView(Post post, View v, ViewGroup parent)  {
    ...
    ParseUser author = post.getParseUser("postAuthor");
    ...
}
```

But I can't populate any views in my UI with attributes from the ParseUser object, such as author.getString("name"); throws null pointer exception. I added this check

```
ParseUser author = post.getParseUser("postAuthor");
if (author == null) {
        Log.i("check1", "author is null!");
}
```

and found that indeed the ParseUser is not retrieved with the Post object at all. I tried changing it to

```
ParseUser author = (ParseUser)post.getParseObject("postAuthor");
```

but to no avail.

Am I missing something here or is it just not supposed to work this way? Should I instead use something like author.fetch() in the getItemView() instead and remove query.include() from create() ?

Comment: Sometimes the built in classes like User and Installation behave differently in ways that are not well documented.  I don't know if this is one of those cases.  I would definitely try `fetch` and see if it works, although that will require a network trip for each record, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @nasch Yes I did try using `fetch` for each item and it works to populate the listview. But this probably uses a large share out of my limited free api requests, doesn't it?

Comment: @nasch Also, should i ditch the ParseQueryAdapter and implement a custom listadapter and directly use query.findInBackground() which will ideally work after query.include()? If yes, it would be of great help if you could point me to such an implementation of a custom adapter using ParseQuery.

Comment: I would try the query outside of the query adapter first - just run it somewhere in your app and don't worry about the list view, just see if the authors come back.  Then you'll know if there's even any reason to keep going that way.  And yes the fetch method will use API requests though of course I have no idea how many.